# Spring Boot 2 and migrating OAuth2 configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

We are migrating our Spring Boot 1.5.7 application to Spring Boot 2 and I noticed that `SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER` is not available anymore.

We were using `@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER))` to force a certain order of security config filters and it is not working without this annotation anymore (getting different statuses since the security filters are in a wrong order). Is there some replacement or configuration change to make it work in the old way?

We have basic auth + OAuth2 in place.

This is the OAuth2 dependency we use:

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.security.oauth', name: 'spring-security-oauth2', version: '2.1.0.RELEASE'
```

EDIT: this is my WebSecurity properties:

```
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  private static final String LOGIN = "/login";
  private static final String LOGOUT_SUCCESS = "/login?logout";

  private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
  private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

  public WebSecurityConfig(UserDetailsService userDetailsService, @Lazy AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    // @formatter:off
    http
      // enable cors
      .cors().and()
      .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/oauth/**", "/*").and()
      // These from the above are secured by the following way
      .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll()
      // These from the rest are secured by the following way
      .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
      // Set login page
      .formLogin().loginPage(LOGIN).permitAll().defaultSuccessUrl(PROFILE)
      // Set logout handling
      .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl(LOGOUT_SUCCESS);
      // @formatter:on

  }

  @Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**");
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
  }

}
```

When accessing `/user` via REST, I expect to get `401 - Unauthorized` without a valid token. Instead, I get `302 - Redirect to /login` meaning that basic auth has higher priority. I am not sure how to fix this since any order I try to use does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it turns out that the problem was not in my WebSecurity config but it was a bit more complex. Spring Security 5 requires clientSecret to be encrypted with BCrypt by default, which I was missing. Also, adding `AuthenicationManager` bean fixed the issue.

```
@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
           return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}
```

I have an example project with this functionality on [github](https://github.com/Smedzlatko/spring-boot2-oauth2) but I am going to improve it a bit to fix some additional issues.

Comment: So what is the order? Which filter is called first? OAuth or Basic? Thanks

Comment: First of all, basic auth comes into places since you need to provide clientId and secret to obtain the token. After that, it's just OAuth

Comment: I'm trying to expose the AuthenticationManager but it says " A dependency cycle was detected when trying to resolve the AuthenticationManager" have you encountered this as well?

Answer (score 2):

Have same issue. Just for monkey patching (will investigate real meaning of `@Order` annotation later), I found what value has been assigned to `ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER` in 1.5.* version from there https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.10.RELEASE/api/ , which appears to be `@Order(2147483640)`...

Comment: Previously, this was defined as [SecurityProperties.BASIC_AUTH_ORDER - 2](https://github.com/joansmith/spring-boot/blob/410dedc5675121da87cdbb83a53ad43179982407/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/SecurityProperties.java#L45-L46) which evaluates to 2147483640, but is more expressive and so easier for readers to understand than an esoteric integer value.